# Metódo ignorando a função callback num plugin jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugin, front-end, funções

Estou desenvolvendo um plugin em jQuery e o problema ou dificuldade é:

Criei os métodos **`init`**, **`show`** e **`hide`**;

```
(function( $ )
    $.fn.tooltip = function(method, onClick, onBefore, onAfter) {

        var default = {
            'onClick' : function() {},
            'onBefore': function() {},
            'onAfter' : function() {},
        };

        var settings = $.extend({}, default, options);

        var methods = {
           init : function(options) {
              return this.each(function(){
                  var $this = $(this);
                  methods.show.apply($this);
                  settings.onClick.call($this);
              });
           },
           show : function() {
              return this.each(function(){
                  var $this = $(this);
                  settings.onBefore.call($this);
                  //Aqui vem a manipulação de classes...
                  .
                  .
                  .
                  .
                  .
                  methods.close.apply($this);
              });
           },
           hide : function() {
              return this.each(function(){
                  var $this = $(this);
                  settings.onAfter.call($this);
                  //Aqui vem a manipulação de classes...
              });
           }
        };

        if ( methods[method] ) {
            return methods[ method ].apply( this, Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 ));
        } 
        else if ( typeof method === 'object' || ! method ) {
            return methods.init.apply( this, arguments );
        } 
        else {
            $.error( 'Method ' +  method + ' does not exist on jQuery.tooltip' );
        }    
    };
})( jQuery );
```

Quando eu chamo através do método **`init`** tudo funciona perfeitamente, mas quando eu chamo através do método hide `$('#test').myPlugin('hide');` o método hide é executado, porém a função de callback **`settings.onAfter($this);`** é ignorada.

Chamando o método `init`

```
$('#test').myPlugin({
    onClick: function(){
        $('.button').myPlugin('hide');
    },
    onBefore: function(){
        $('body').addClass('onBefore');
    },
    onAfter: function(){
        $('body').addClass('onAfter');
    }
});
```

Quando eu chamo o método `init` ele chama o `show`, este método faz tudo que precisa ser feito (manipulação de classes) e depois de tudo ele chama o método `hide`. O `hide` faz tudo o que precisa ser feito também e em seguida chama a função de callback `onAfter`, perfeito!

Mas quando eu chamo o método `hide` através da função callback `onClick`, ele executa o método certinho, somente ignora o callback `onAfter`

Comment: Post o código todo, inclusive o que vc está usando para teste

Comment: @EmirMarques, prontinho! Não sei se ficou bem claro o meu problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fiz alguns ajustes no teu código. Da uma roda esse exemplo e olha o console do navegador.

```js
   $(function(){
   $("#ipTeste").tooltip('hide');
   //$("#ipTeste").tooltip('show');
   //$("#ipTeste").tooltip('init');
});

(function($){
    $.fn.tooltip = function(method) {
        
        var defaultV = {
            'onClick' : function(el) {
                console.log("onClick...");
            },
            'onBefore': function(el) {
                console.log("onBefore...");
            },
            'onAfter' : function(el) {
                console.log("onAfter...");
                defaultV.onBefore();
                defaultV.onClick();
                
                $(el).tooltip('show');
                $(el).tooltip('init');
            }
        };
        
        var settings = $.extend({}, defaultV);
        
        var methods = {
            init : function(options) {
                return this.each(function(){
                    console.log("INIT...");
                    var $this = $(this);
                    settings.onClick.call({}, $this);
                    //Aqui vem a manipulação de classes...
                });
            },
            show : function() {
                return this.each(function(){
                    console.log("SHOW...");
                    var $this = $(this);
                    settings.onBefore.call({}, $this);
                    //Aqui vem a manipulação de classes...
                });
            },
            hide : function() {
                return this.each(function(){
                    console.log("HIDE...");
                    var $this = $(this);
                    settings.onAfter.call({}, $this);
                    //Aqui vem a manipulação de classes...
                });
            }
        };
        
        if ( methods[method] ) {
            return methods[ method ].apply( this, Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 ));
        } 
        else if ( typeof method === 'object' || ! method ) {
            return methods.init.apply( this, arguments );
        } 
        else {
            $.error( 'Method ' +  method + ' does not exist on jQuery.tooltip' );
        }   
    };
})( jQuery );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="ipTeste"/>
```

Comment: Sim, neste caso funciona perfeitamente! O problema é que se eu coloco uma função de `click` chamando o metodo `hide` dentro da minha função de callback `onClick` o callback que é chamando dentro do método hide não executa.

Comment: Deixa ver se entendi. Aqui onde colocquei o console.log("onClick...");, vc quer chamar por exemplo o onBefore. É isso?

Comment: Na verdade seria no call do plugin: `$('#test').myPlugin({onClick: function(){$('.button').myPlugin('hide');}});`

Comment: Da uma olhada agora

Comment: Perfeito Emir! Muito obrigado.